# Re-entry to Japan within 90 days period as a tourist?

Tags: visas, japan, tourist-visas, eu-citizens

I am a European citizen with Spanish passport and therefore I needed no visa for tourism in Japan. I was given a 90 day period (Sep 16 to max. Dec 15) and within that period I must go to the US for an interview (Nov 30 to Dec 5)

My flight back home to Spain is on Dec 14 so it is not an extension of my original period what I am after. 
I just need to interrupt my holiday for this specific thing and I am afraid of not being able to re-enter, join my (also Spanish) wife again and finish our vacation normally.

Is there any objective information about the regulations regarding re-entry for this type of permit?

Comment: When you leave Japan you'll have to hand in the paper you filled in, so I think when you return you won't be resuming that period but starting a new one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is not a problem. When you leave you will hand in the form that is presently stapled into your passport and you will be stamped out. When you return you will get a new 90 day period (in my experience).

It is possible that the immigration inspector will notice that you have been in Japan very recently. She/he may ask you about it. Of course you should be honest. However, since you intend to leave before your original 90 day period is up, you cannot be accused of trying to extend your period with a visa run. You may want to have a copy of your itinerary handy to show this.

Informally, I do not think Japan is worried about westerners coming to visit and making frequent entries, as long as they do not break the rules. I have always found the immigration staff to be very polite, courteous and friendly.

Answer (score 1):

Observation:  US passport, we had an overnight connection in Tokyo.  On the return flight we also had an overnight connection.  This second entry didn't cause any scrutiny from the official and unless his computer found our tickets he didn't know it was just an overnight connection.  (This actually made economic sense--it was part of an airline promo deal, they were putting us up at a hotel near the airport.  The tickets were no more than the direct flight would have been, we got to spend some hours looking around at basically zero cost.)

Comment: He did know because you filled out a form stating how long you intended to stay in Japan and gave it to him.

Comment: @Calchas I sure don't remember a question like that but it's been some years.

Comment: the landing card includes a field where you give your "intended length of stay in Japan", nearly divided into years, months and days. :). This has been the case for at least four years.

Comment: @Calchas This was more than 10 years ago.